# Passing additional arguments to an event callback function

Tags: javascript, callback, arguments, dom-events

I need to pass additional arguments to a function on an event.

I tried `bind` but it only passes the `e` and not the result `data`:

```
locationSearch.on("result", dropMarker.bind(this, e) );
```

I could do:

```
locationSearch.on("result", function(data) {
    dropMarker({ 
        e: e,
        data: data
    });
};
```

... but then I can't disable the listener `locationSearch.off(...)` since it is an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the function call in another function that will become the callback

```
locationSearch.on("result", wrapper);

function wrapper(e) { dropMarker(e, data); }
```

Here's an example:

```js
$("button").on("click", wrapper);

let data = "some data";

function wrapper(e){
  // The wrapper just calls the actual handler
  handler(e, data);
}

function handler(e, data){
  // Because the wrapper was named, it can be disconnected
  $(e.target).off("click", wrapper);
  
  // And you can do whatever you need to
  console.log(e.type, data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: Yea, but the library doesn't provide a `one` or `once` emitter so I also need to turn off the listener immediately which isn't possible with an anonymous function, right?

Comment: But again, you can't disable the listener as stated in the question since it's an anonymous function.

Comment: I've updated the answer. With a named function, you can remove the handler.

Answer (score 0):

Just name a function and then call it:

```
function handler(e) {
    dropMarker({ e: e, data: data });
}

locationSearch.on("result", handler);
```